# Find pages with tag

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

In a Umbraco 7 solution, i have a Tags Content picker on all pages. Pages can with this, set tags on each page.

I then want to get alle pages, within the intire site, that has, lets say tag 111 (id, not name).

I have tried with:

```
var ids = Model.MacroParameters["tags"]; //the tags to show
CurrentPage.AncestorOrSelf(1).Descendants().Where(x => ids.Contains(x.tags.ToString()));
```

But that gives me the error:

```
Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type
```

Whats the correct way?

Answer (score 1):

Solved it with;

```
Umbraco.Content(rootId).Descendants().Where("tags.Contains(@0)", ids);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options, depending on whether you prefer a dynamic or strongly typed view model.

**Strongly Typed API**

```
Umbraco.TypedContentAtRoot().Descendants().Where(x => x.tags.Contains(ids));
```

**Dynamic API**

```
Umbraco.ContentAtRoot().Descendants().Where("tags.Contains(@0)", ids);
```

Please note that the *Contains* statement may give you inconsistent results, as the *tags* property seems to be returning a comma separated list. In that case you can try splitting the string or install the [Core Property Value Converters package](https://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/umbraco-core-property-value-converters/) and get the tags as `IEnumerable<IPublishedContent>`

Answer (score 0):

Always try to avoid using Descendants, especially on the root node.
To get the tags for a property:

```
ApplicationContext.Current.Services.TagService.GetTagsForProperty(Model.Content.Id, "propertyname")
```

To find content with a specific tag:

```
ApplicationContext.Current.Services.TagService.GetTaggedContentByTag("tag")
```